# JavaScript: Convert [a,b,c] into [a][b][c]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays like `[a]`, `[a,b]`, `[a,b,c]` and so on.

How can I convert them into `[a]`, `[a][b]`, `[a][b][c]` and so on?

Example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
    arr = do(arr); // arr = arr[1][2][3][4]
```

Comment: The expression `[a][b][c]` means, "Create an `Array`: `[a]`. Index that array with the value `b`. Index *that* value with the value `c`." Is that what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @this-vidor I mean 3D, 4D, ... array if you mean that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could map it with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).That returns an array with the processed values.

ES6

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].map(a => [a]));
```

ES5

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (a) {
    return [a];
}));
```

While the question is a bit unclear, and I think the OP needs possibly a string in the wanted form, then this would do it.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function (r, a) {
    return r + '[' + a + ']';
}, 'arr'));
```

Comment: `a` is the variable for an element of the array.

Comment: the function/lambda expression inside the map is called once per element in the `arr` array.  Each time `a` refers to the "current" element for that call.

Comment: Why my PhpStorm IDE catch your first expression as error and said: "Variable a is implicitly declared"?

Comment: do you get the error with the first or the second one?

Comment: The first one only.

Comment: maybe you IDE does not understand ES6 syntax. please try the second one.

Comment: Your IDE almost certainly does not understand ES6, looks like there is a plugin available for you: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7643?pr=

Comment: So the first one is newer version of ECMAScript.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, I think I've just checked the post as answer incorrectly. I want [1][2][3] instead of [[1],[2],[3]].

Comment: `[1][2][3]` that is not valid for data. it may be valid for access.

Comment: @NinaScholz Is <input name="some[1][2][3]" /> valid? If yes, What is the equivalent in JavaScript?

Comment: that is a valid name. would like to generate a string instead?

Comment: I want to create it with JavaScript

Comment: either see above or would you like to generate the input tag?

Answer (score 4):

**Functional:**

use `.map` like this

`[1,2,3,4].map(i => [i])`

**Iterative:**

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4], result = [];

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    result.push([list[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are converting single dimension array to multi dimensional array. 
To do so,

```
var inputArray = [1,2,3,4];
var outputArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++)
{
    outputArray.push([inputArray[i]])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function map(arr){
  var aux = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length;++i){
    var aux2 = [];
    aux2.push(arr[i]);
    aux.push(aux2);
  }
  return aux;
}
```